# UIGraphicsImageRenderer generates a strange top padding on iOS 15, working fine on iOS 14.x

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, core-graphics

iOS 15 generates a strange top padding when I export a SwiftUI View to image using UIGraphicsImageRenderer . It works fine on iOS 14.x . Any one has an idea why?
[image: screenshot]

[image: code]

Comment: You showed 2 different images, try to show the issue with same image in both version. PS: I think the issue is other thing in your codes and show the view that you use that function.

Comment: Have you checked to see that the `intrinsicContentSize` matches your expectations about how large the image should be.  Many views don't really have an intrinsic size so it wouldn't surprise me if that's an issue.

Answer (score 7):

It turns out to be a real issue of iOS 15.

I posted the same question on Twitter and It has been replied with a working solution.

You can read more about the problem [here](https://www.vinzius.com/post/how-to-remove-padding-when-snapshotting-swiftui-view-ios15/)

The solution is in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/Vinzius/3196230a2902d4ad9d0d3a55d89befe1)

I post the gist here for completeness, but all credit goes to its author (not me):

```
//
//  View+Snapshot.swift
//
//  Created by Vinzius on 2021-11-06.
//

import SwiftUI
import UIKit.UIImage
import UIKit.UIGraphicsImageRenderer

extension View {
    
    func snapshot() -> UIImage? {
        
        // Note: since iOS 15 it seems these two modifiers are required.
        let controller = UIHostingController(
            rootView: self.ignoresSafeArea()
                .fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: true)
        )
        guard let view = controller.view else { return nil }
        
        let targetSize = view.intrinsicContentSize
        if targetSize.width <= 0 || targetSize.height <= 0 { return nil }
        
        view.bounds = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: targetSize)
        view.backgroundColor = .clear

        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: targetSize)
        
        return renderer.image { _ in
            view.drawHierarchy(in: controller.view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
        }
        
    }
    
}
```